# Django, drf-yasg - how to add description to tags?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-yasg

Swagger documentation says you can do that:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/

But unfortunately drf-yasg not implementing this feature:

https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/454

It is said, that I can add custom generator class, but it is a very general answer.  Now I see that `drf_yasg.openapi.Swagger` gets `info` block and I have thoughts, that this might be right place to put global `tags` section as an additional init argument, but it deeper, than customizing generator class and I have lack of knowledge of this module

Does anybody have solution to this particular problem, or at least maybe a link to some sort of tutorial, how to properly customize generator class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a [current issue](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues/454) with drf-yasg.

To actually achieve this, you need to create your own schema generator class:

```
from drf_yasg.generators import OpenAPISchemaGenerator

class CustomOpenAPISchemaGenerator(OpenAPISchemaGenerator):
  def get_schema(self, request=None, public=False):
    """Generate a :class:`.Swagger` object with custom tags"""

    swagger = super().get_schema(request, public)
    swagger.tags = [
        {
            "name": "api",
            "description": "everything about your API"
        },
        {
            "name": "users",
            "description": "everything about your users"
        },
    ]

    return swagger
```

Make sure to also include it in your Schema View

```
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
  openapi.Info(
    title="My API",
    default_version='v1',
  ),
  generator_class=CustomOpenAPISchemaGenerator,
)
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is exactly what your are looking for, but I think it might help.

To set tags I use `@swagger_auto_schema decorator`, which can be applied in a few different ways depending mostly on the type of `Views` used on your project. Complete details can be found on docs [here](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator).

When using `Views` derived from `APIView`, you could do something like this:

```
class ClientView(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(tags=['my custom tag'])
    def get(self, request, client_id=None):
        pass
```

According to the [docs](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/drf_yasg.html#drf_yasg.openapi.Operation), the limitation is that `tags` only takes a list of strs as value. So from here on, I believe there is no support for extra attributes over tags as stated at Swagger docs, [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/grouping-operations-with-tags/).

Anyway, if you only need to define a *summary* or a *description* to obtain something like the image below, you could define them using the decorator or a class-level docstring. Here is an example:

[image: tag with desc and summary]

[image]

```
class ClientView(APIView):
    '''
    get:
    Client List serialized as JSON.

    This is a description from a class level docstring.

    '''
    def get(self, request, client_id=None):
        pass
    
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_description="POST description override using 
            decorator",
        operation_summary="this is the summary from decorator",
        
        # request_body is used to specify parameters
        request_body=openapi.Schema(
            type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT,
            required=['name'],
            properties={
                'name': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
            },
        ),
        tags=['my custom tag']
    )
    def post(self, request):
        pass
```

Good luck!